# Is it possible to detect the mobile device model using javascript or ASP.Net

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, .net

I have a website that will display mobile accessories and I'm thinking that it would be nice if the website was able to detect the user's mobile device that's requesting the page so it would display products for this specific model.

Any way to achieve this in javascript, jQuery or .Net is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you can get model number. But anyway can you try with all request headers and see you can find out the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Detecting the client reliably is not easy, but the best you can do is to look in the user agent string supplied by the client.

In ASP.NET you can access it through `Request.UserAgent` property.

You will have to find the exact user agents that you want to look for to identify phone models. This is for example my old Xperia Mini Pro:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.3.4; sv-se; SonyEricssonSK17i Build/4.0.2.A.0.58) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Vers
```

Comment: well, that's not going to be easy to code nor to maintain
isn't there another way or workaround to do it ?